# Convert php function to kotlin

Tags: php, kotlin

How to convert this php function to kotlin?

```
function round_up($number, $precision = 2)
{
    $fig = pow(10, $precision);
    return (ceil($number * $fig) / $fig);
}
```

I try to do this but is not working

```
 fun round_up(number: Float, precision = 2){
    val fig = pow(10,precision)
    return (ceil(number * fig) / fig)
 }
```

Expected usage:

```
    val currentFloatValue = 1.568
    val finalValue = round_up(currentFloatValue)
    // result should be
    // 1.57
```

Comment: You can't represent the decimal number 1.57 exactly in binary. Your very approach is flawed therefore, you need a decimal type if you want to round to decimal places. Or, better, you don't round until you convert the number to text, where you do that implicitly via the format specification. Btw: "is not working" is not a useful problem description, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was nearly correct:

- Use `Double` and not `Float`, because this is the default floating point number in Kotlin.
- Define a type for the `precision` parameter, e.g. Int
- Define a return type, e.g. Double

```
fun round_up(number: Double, precision: Int = 2): Double {
    val fig = pow(10.0, precision.toDouble())
    return ceil(number * fig) / fig
}
```